# Bootstrap: Subnav does not have the same style as on demo site

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap subnav does not look the same as the one on the demo site. Here's my markup:

```
<div class="subnav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li><a href="#demoModal">Modal</a></li>
        <li><a href="#demoTabs">Tabs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#demoAccordion">Accordion</a></li>
        <li><a href="#demoOther">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and an image of what I am seeing:

[image: Bad]

and here is what I am trying to replicate:

[image: Good]

I tried copying the markup exactly, but to no avail. I wondered if maybe it had something to do with the parent elements being different.. so I moved mine into a "container-fluid" classed div, but that didn't help. Maybe someone here can spot something my eye missed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the style is not included in bootstrap. You can grab the docs.css from their markup and reference that. That seems to be the CSS that is giving the sub-nav the styling you are looking for.

i.e.
[image]